# How can I slice a specific string?

Tags: javascript

```js
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] =======[]=======
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] Playtime: 2hrs 50mins 50s
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] Times joined: 18
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] Joined Date: 02/12/2021
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] ============================
```

This is a piece of text here and I want to slice off anything in the `[]`, how can I do that?

Comment: What is the ecxpected ouput? Also where is the related code?

Comment: Can you show us some code please? How can we get this string?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
const text = `[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] =======[]=======
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] Playtime: 2hrs 50mins 50s
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] Times joined: 18
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] Joined Date: 02/12/2021
[Tue, 6. Apr 2021 13:56:55 UTC INFO] ============================`;
const content = text
  .split("\n")
  .map(line => line.split("]")[1].trim())
  .filter(line => !line.startsWith("="))
console.log(content.join("\n"))
```